# how can i see inputs in html

Tags: javascript, html, input

I want to make a program that makes it so that every time I type into an `<input>` the text I put in it appears above it.

```
<center><h1><tag name></h1>
    <input tag='name' type='text' placeholder="Name" maxlength="10" minlength="2">
    <br>
    <input tag='pass' type='password' minlength='7' maxlength='20' placeholder="Password" >
    <input type='submit'>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need JavaScript for that. What you can do is:

```html
<p>You typed: <code id="out"></code></p>

<p>Type Something:</p>
<input id="text" placeholder="Type Something..." onkeyup="out.innerHTML = this.value;" />
```

I have used `onkeyup` event here and instead of using:

```
document.getElementById("out")
```

I have used just `out`. This is not a right practice, but for simplicity I did this for you.

Here's a preview:

[image: preview]